# Android add images from OBB directory to Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-mediascanner

I am trying to scan images which are stored in the OBB directory to the Gallery (in this case Google Photos).

If I scan from the Pictures Folder everything works fine.

Working code:

```
String outputDir = String.format("%s/%s", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"Pictures");
```

OBB directory code:

```
String outputDir = String.format("%s/%s", context.getObbDir(),"Pictures");
```

For scanning:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                new String[] { picture.getUrl() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        System.out.print("Scanned " + path);
                    }
                });
```

`picture.getUrl()` is in this case the file url. It is stored in a data object first and then sent to the scanner.

Comment: does the picture folder or one of it-s parent folders contain a ".nomedia" file that forbids the media scanner to index the images?

Comment: yeah it does. Sorry I haven't checked that. This is the solution to my problem. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added my comment as answer so the question can be marked as answerd.

If the the picture folder or one of it-s parent folders contain a ".nomedia" file the media scanner will not index the image(s)